# How to use IAM roles attached to AWS Cognito user pool groups with Identity pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a cognito user pool with many groups. Each group is associated with an IAM role. A user in the pool can be a member of more than one group. I also have an identity pool for which the cognito user pool is the identity provider. The problem I'm running into has two parts.

1. I am unable to use the precedence ordering for the group roles. This is because the IAM roles have different permissions and there is no point in ordering them. A user will select the group/role that they want to use which rules out any system for ranking them. This rules out using the cognito:preferred_role field in the identity token.

2)I then looked at using the rule based mappings in conjunction with a custom attribute. This way a role could be specified in the custom attribute and then the token could be regenerated. However, the rule based mapping only allows 25 rules per identity pool and this is not nearly enough for our the number of groups/roles.

Lastly, I looked at using the CustomRoleArn parameter in the GetCredentialsForIdentity API method. When using it I got an error saying "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Only SAML providers and providers with RoleMappings support custom role ARN". This brings us back to the 25 rule limit.

So is there a way to specify an IAM role for and authenticated user to assume that isn't some obtuse ordering system or limited by the number of rules I can use?